# In a Rails has_many through relationship, can the intermediary model serve more than two other models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Given the following:

```
class Physician < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :appointments
  has_many :patients, through: :appointments
end

class Appointment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :physician
  belongs_to :patient
end

class Patient < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :appointments
  has_many :physicians, through: :appointments
end
```

If one were so inclined, could the `:appointments` model also serve other models as well? For example, my grandmother desires to use a site to make appointments for her `:dentist`, too, and maybe the `:dietitian` as well (it's a big hospital.) Can I do this via the "middleman" `:appointments` for all of them, or must I use different models for each?

My own app is not using these examples, they are just to illustrate. Another example would be, using `:selection` for not only `:likes` but also `:follow-ees` as well, such as in a Facebook-Twitter union. You select for both people to follow, and also select for their content you like. Is this ok to do in Rails?

Comment: You are probably looking for polymorphic associations:http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations

Answer (score 1):

Below is something you might want to try, but it could also be helpful to specify what you're **actually** trying to model, because your theoretical question can only be answered with theoretical solutions. Real solutions are so much better!

```
RelatedModel1
  has_many :related_model2s, through: :common_model
  has_many :related_model3s, through: :common_model
  has_many :related_model4s, through: :common_model

CommonModel
  belongs_to :related_model1
  belongs_to :related_model2
  belongs_to :related_model3

RelatedModel2
  has_many :related_model1s, through: :common_model

RelatedModel3
  has_many :related_model1s, through: :common_model

RelatedModel4
  has_many :related_model1s, through: :common_model
```

In this scenario, you could probably also say:

```
RelatedModel4
  has_many :related_model3s, through: :common_model`
```

In other words, they all have many of each other, through the common model.